# Auto Set User/Team Lookup Field Value Using Power Automate In D365

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, power-automate, dynamics-365

In my project I want to set the user/team lookup field value in Test table with power automate flow.

But I want to not set directly field value, I have one field which is in Account table(Field Name is User) which is also user/team lookup field. I want to set, when the Account table lookup field is user then set field value(As Account Table User) in Test table and when the Account table field value is team then set the same field value(As Account Table Team) in Test table.

Actually when I add Account table look up field is User and I have added expression in user and team respectively it was show the error as below.

[image]

My Expressions are:

1.for User: `if(empty(outputs('Get_Account_Details')?['body/_new_user_value']),concat('systemusers(',outputs('Get_a_row_by_ID_-_Get_Account_Owner')?['body/_parentsystemuserid_value'],')'),outputs('User_is_user'))`

2. For Team: `if(empty(outputs('Get_Account_Details')?['body/_new_user_value']),'',outputs('Team_is_team'),)`

If I use above expression for User and Account table User(Field) is user then It's properly work but when I use both expressions it was not work.

Currently my Account table field is team then,

[image]

I got the team and not getting User which is Correct but when I set this compose in field output it getting the error.

Anyone Help?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to find out entity schema name of field `_new_user_value` If it is systemuser then set as systemuser, if not it is Team

For a Field `_new_user_value_` you will have option in power automate as Entity Name, check that if it is Team or user and based on it you can perfrom setting value.

Comment: But I want to set it's dynamically. Suppose One record have user and another record have team then what to do?

Comment: Can please check I have edited the question

Comment: you are most probably using dataverse connector, check the output of your trigger or above step, you will find _new_user_value_ entity type as dynamics i.e when user then systemuser when Team then Team as entity schema name. This is dynamic.